# AWS EventBridge multiple targets in single event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-event-bridge

In AWS Eventbridge we can have up to 5 targets in one rule/event. Do these targets execute synchronously or asynchronously?

If it happens asynchronously is there a way to make it synchronous.

The target type is - Redshift cluster

I have to trigger two Redshift queries one after another using the event bridge by creating two redshift targets inside the event.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how it works and what you can do?

Comment: Thanks for asking.

Yes, I don't want to use the Lambda function as then I will have to use the redshift API to trigger the redshift schedule query/ Stored Procedure.

I just want to schedule normal (insert/update) queries in a synchronous-asynchronous manner.

Using EventBridge I can schedule up to 5 Asynchronous queries which can run in the redshift cluster.
But some dependent queries I want to run synchronously.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I agree.
Okay

Comment: can you try using `event bridge put event` as a target for an event scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its async as written in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html). There is no way to change that.

You should re-architect your application, for example your first lambda, upon finish, triggers a second lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to trigger your actions in order.